# Visual Studio 2010 source annotation keywords cause name clashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After having converted a project from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010, it appears the project doesn't build anymore and spits out tons of `C2059` errors like:

`error C2059: syntax error : 'type'

We're using Visual Studio 2010 Professional which doesn't provide static code analysis.

Here is the full log for the compilation of 1 C file for reference:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: VoHR, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  AKAsynch.c
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(88): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(107): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(119): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(139): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down the reason of those sudden compiler errors.

In the great tradition of `windows.h` it appears that Microsoft introduced tokens that cause name clashes with our codebase.

In our precise case, we had:
`#define Null (void*)0`

Somewhere in our code, we need to use the `offsetof` macro and to make it available we `#include <stddef.h>`

I tracked down `stddef.h` in turns includes `crtdefs.h` which ends up including `sal.h` where our `Null` macro seems to clash with source code annotation in MS headers...

As a workaround, we did:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1600
#pragma push_macro("Null")
#undef Null
#endif
#include <stddef.h>
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1600
#pragma pop_macro("Null")
#endif
```

Our use of `Null` as a macro is arguable, still I would have expected MS to find a way to avoid clashes with existing code bases.

Hope that helps those facing the same issue.